# Iterate over an array of classes and push certain properties into an array

Tags: php, functional-programming, iteration, declarative

Here is the code that will iterate over an array of classes, and push the `content_id` property of each element (if it exists) into an array:

```
# Collect content jobs ids from the job to process
$jobsToProcessContentIds = [];
foreach ( $jobsToProcess as $job ) {
    if ( $job->content_id ?? null ) {
        array_push( $jobsToProcessContentIds, $job->content_id );
    }
}
```

Is there a shorter, more declarative way to achieve this?

Comment: `$jobsToProcessContentIds[] = $job->content_id;`

Answer (score 0):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/769649)

```
<?php
class x
{
    public $content_id="y";
}
class y
{
    public $content="z";
}
$jobsToProcess=array(new x(), new y());


$jobsToProcessContentIds=array();
foreach ($jobsToProcess as $job)
{
    if (property_exists($job, "content_id"))
    {
        $jobsToProcessContentIds[]=$job->content_id;
    }
}
print_r($jobsToProcessContentIds);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => y
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be much shorter but it seems a good choice for a declarative approach is to use [array_reduce()](http://php.net/array_reduce).

```
$jobsToProcessContentIds = array_reduce($jobsToProcess, function($carry, $job) {
    if ($job->content_id ?? null) {
        $carry[] = $job->content_id;
    }
    return $carry;
});
```

Two lines could be saved by using the short-circuiting [logical AND operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (i.e. `&&`), though some would argue it is less readable.

```
$jobsToProcessContentIds = array_reduce($jobsToProcess, function($carry, $job) {
    ($job->content_id ?? null) && $carry[] = $job->content_id;
    return $carry;
});
```

See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2m56-vh45).